# Не работает кнопка стандартного поиска на теме Вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт с премиум темой Kassandra от Goodwin. Установил на проект и столкнулся с тем, что на ней не работает кнопка поиска.

Сам сайт - https://otvetzdes.ru/ Скриншот расположения кнопки поиска на сайте: [image: Скрин расположения кнопки поиска]

**В чем может быть дело?**

Comment: у вас полно ошибок в консоли, исправьте их и думаю все заработает

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Обновил тему до последней версии и все исправилось.